# How to edit/rename Column total field in crosstab of crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

i am working with crystal report 2008

in crosstab I have:

```
A   aa      1
    bb      2
    cc      0
    dd      1
**Total**   4

B   tt      0
    yy      1
    hh      0
    jj      1
**Total**   2
```

Where A and B are 1st group by data, aa, bb, cc....are 2nd group by data.1,2...are summary values.Total is column total below the 2nd group by.

I want the **Total** field to be as **A Total** and **B Total**...

Can anyone plz help me out from this.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to do this is with a calculated member row.
But this gets very complex as you need to hide the totals, and a calculated member by default is listed as a total so you will need a calculated member for each level of the groups.

[This Link](http://www.crystalkeen.com/articles/crystalreports/crosstabcalcmember.htm) give some useful information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...
I did it successfully with the calculated member row.
I think it is the only way to do this.