# Change the name of the Row Header of a Cross Tab in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to change the name **Total**  to **Gross Salary**.
[image]

I don't need to edit the text as the same cross tab repeats for few more groups.So the next one is to be **Total Allowances**. How to do it functionally.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you will make your cross-tab very complicated and don't know if it's worth for one column rename. It can be done in several ways.

Check [this](https://scn.sap.com/thread/3373852) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607837/how-to-edit-rename-column-total-field-in-crosstab-of-crystal-report) for more help/answers about your problem.

**EDIT:**

I have tried to edit it in design mode in my crystal and on doubleclick on that column name i can rename it as desired. Which version are you using?

Comment: VS 2005 embedded Crystal Report

Comment: Then you will probably have to change column names by using 2 links which i provided you (which will probably make your simple report very complicated). I'm using CR 14.1.4.1327 and can rename that column very simple.